# RAILS - How to define group in associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have two associated tables whose models are as shown below.

Here I would like to fetch all "ilans" which are **"created_at OR has an associated record (ilanupdates) during the last 36 hours"**

Models:

```
class Ilan < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ilanupdates
end

class Ilanupdate < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ilan
end
```

I have problem defining the controller method which generates an error related to GROUP definition. I will appreciate if you can guide me how to solve this issue.

Controller:

```
 def index
    @ilans = Ilan.left_outer_joins(:ilanupdates).select("ilans.*, count(ilanupdates.*) as ilanupdate_count, max(ilanupdates.old_price) as highest_price").group(:id)
    @ilans = @ilans.where("ilans.created_at > ? OR (ilanupdates.created_at > ?", (Time.now - 36.hours),(Time.now - 36.hours))
    @ilans = @ilans.order('ilans.ad_date DESC, ilanupdate_count DESC, ilans.price ASC')
 end
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GROUP" LINE 1
```

Comment: Its just a syntax mistake please remove the opening braces in the second query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its a syntax mistake,
It should be:

```
@ilans = Ilan.left_outer_joins(:ilanupdates).select("ilans.*, count(ilanupdates.*) as ilanupdate_count, max(ilanupdates.old_price) as highest_price").group(:id)
@ilans = @ilans.where("ilans.created_at > ? OR ilanupdates.created_at > ?", (Time.now - 36.hours),(Time.now - 36.hours))
@ilans = @ilans.order('ilans.ad_date DESC, ilanupdate_count DESC, ilans.price ASC')
```

Comment: Please specify what exactly you changed

Comment: In second query **OR ilanupdates.created_at instead** of **OR (ilanupdates.created_at**

Comment: I mean in answer

Comment: The query you write has error  "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GROUP" will solve if you remove the opening braces from the second line near ilanupdates.created_at